# Do aftereffects trigger upon death?

Tags: dnd-4e

The druid power Fires of Life has an aftereffect where a creature can gain 5 hit points. It also has the ability for a creature to gain 5 hit points if the target reaches 0 hit points before the target saves against the ongoing damage.

Does the aftereffect trigger upon death? Death would seem to mean that the effect 'ended'.

If so, that would seem to mean that that's 5HP x2 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An aftereffect happens after an effect ends. In this case, when the monster saves.

Unfortunately, if the creature *dies* before he saves, the monster *never saved* and thus the power doesn't trigger (the effect, in effect, doesn't end, at least in a normal way).

This is *why* the text for the Hit has a clause for when they  "[reach] 0 HP."

So no, death doesn't let it double up, the death clause allows it to happen at all.